# A subset of a sortedset in Groovy (or Java)

Tags: java, groovy

Have a SortedSet where I need a specific slice of records based on a specific element in the list.

Example:
In the code below, challengeDTO.members is a SortedSet (TreeSet implementation)

I know the location of one member

```
def memberRank = challengeDTO.members.findIndexOf { it.member.id == membership?.id} + 1
```

If the memberRank is 66, I want to get a slice of members 60 through 70 ranks.

challengeDTO.members[60..69] won't work because it's a set

Ideas?  Suggestions?

Member implementation:

```
class ChallengeMemberDTO implements Comparable<ChallengeMemberDTO> {

  ChallengeMember member
  Integer total
  String name
  String teamName

  int compareTo(ChallengeMemberDTO t) {
    if (total == t.total) {  // the sortedset will remove duplicates based on same total, which is not desireable
      return name.compareTo(t.name)
    }
    else {
      return t.total.compareTo(total)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
(challengeDTO.members as List)[60..69]
```

Under the covers the Groovy `as List` type conversion creates an instance of `ArrayList` and calls `addAll`, passing your SortedSet. As per the `java.util.List` JavaDoc `addAll` "appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's iterator". In the `java.util.SortedSet` JavaDoc it states that "the set's iterator will traverse the set in ascending element order."

So the order of the list will match the order of the SortedSet.

If you're interested, you can take a look at the method in the Groovy source code:

`org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.asList(Collection<T> self)`

**EDIT:**

For the sake completeness, in Java you could do the following. It's just what the Groovy code above does under the covers:

```
SortedSet<ChallendMemberDTO> memberSet = challengeDTO.getMembers();
List<ChallengeMemberDTO> membersPage = new ArrayList<ChallengeMemberDTO>(memberSet).subList(60, 70);
```

Comment: will return a guaranteed order though?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for that, you have to understand how SortedSet works.

Items that can be used in methods of SortedSet are all those for which the `compare()` method of the Comparator or the `compareTo()` method of the items will return a numeric value.

As a consequence, if the `compareTo()` implementation of your member class allows you to compare members to a number, you can use simply

```
challengeDTO.members.subSet(60, 70)
```

Comment: *if the compareTo() implementation of your member class allows you to compare members to a number* I would strongly advise against that, as that would create a uni-directional comparator. This violates the contract that `sgn(x.compareTo(y))` must equal `-sgn(y.compareTo(x))` (Effective Java 2nd Ed, Item 12)

Comment: Guess what ? I already jnew that. hHowever, there are cases where this is a very efficient shortcut, as the full code would require one to create members with the desired ids (but no other content), then expect default member compareTo method to behave correctly. This is why I precisely say one can also override this SortedSet Comparator field, in order to handle that in a "clean" way.

Comment: I agree with Sean Patrick Floyd that it's a bad idea to break the `Comparator` contract, even for the sake of efficiency (especially since [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth])). Plus, comparing that class to a number is an artefact of view code that should not find its way into the domain. It may be more efficient than a simple `new ArrayList<ChallengeMemberDTO>(challengeDTO.members).subList(60, 70)` - I don't know (it will probably depend mostly on the implementation of `compareTo`). Let the profiler decide, if it's too slow.

Comment: Well, you know - you just have to take these opportunities when they come along...

Answer (score 1):

[`SortedSet<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) has the [`headSet(E)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#headSet%28E%29), [`tailSet(E)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#tailSet%28E%29)and [`subSet(E, E)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#subSet%28E%2C%20E%29) methods for this purpose.

Just pass in a variable that compares correctly with the values you want:

Sample class:

```
public class Member implements Comparable<Member>{

    public Member(final int value){  this.value = value; }
    private final int value;
    public int getValue(){ return value; }

    @Override public int hashCode(){ return 31 * value; }

    @Override public boolean equals(final Object obj){
        return obj instanceof Member && ((Member) obj).value == value;
    }

    @Override public String toString(){ "[Member, value="+value+"]"; }

    @Override public int compareTo(final Member o){
        return Integer.valueOf(value).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o.value));
    }
}
```

Sample code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args){
    final SortedSet<Member> set = new TreeSet<Member>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        set.add(new Member(i));
    }
    System.out.println("TailSet(7): " + set.tailSet(new Member(7)));
    System.out.println("HeadSet(3): " + set.headSet(new Member(3)));
    System.out.println("SubSet(6, 8): " + 
                          set.subSet(new Member(6), new Member(8)));
}
```

Output:

> TailSet(7): [[Member, value=7], [Member, value=8], [Member, value=9]]
>   HeadSet(3): [[Member, value=0], [Member, value=1], [Member, value=2]]
>   SubSet(6, 8): [[Member, value=6], [Member, value=7]]

---

And here's a method that builds the slice (using the `NavigableSet` interface, which is a superset of `SortedSet` and also implemented by `TreeSet`):

```
public static <K> List<K> slice(final NavigableSet<K> set,
    final K reference,
    final int elementsBefore,
    final int elementsAfter){
    final List<K> list = new ArrayList<K>();
    final Iterator<K> headIterator =
        set.headSet(reference, false).descendingIterator();
    int headCt = 0;
    while(headIterator.hasNext() && headCt++ < elementsBefore){
        list.add(0, headIterator.next());
    }
    list.add(reference);
    final Iterator<K> tailIterator =
        set.tailSet(reference, false).iterator();
    int tailCt = 0;
    while(tailIterator.hasNext() && tailCt++ < elementsAfter){
        list.add(tailIterator.next());
    }

    return list;
}
```

Usage:

```
final NavigableSet<Member> set = new TreeSet<Member>();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    set.add(new Member(i));
}
System.out.println(slice(set, new Member(67), 2, 2));
System.out.println(slice(set, new Member(2), 25, 2));
```

Output:

> [[Member, value=65], [Member, value=66], [Member, value=67], [Member, value=68], [Member, value=69]]
>   [[Member, value=0], [Member, value=1], [Member, value=2], [Member, value=3], [Member, value=4]]

Comment: thanks, i edited my original post to show member implemenation